# How to build a Sublime Text 2 plugin to compile racket (scheme) code?

Tags: plugins, scheme, sublimetext2, racket, read-eval-print-loop

I'm envisioning a Sublime Text 2 plugin that allows me in the main window to type in some Racket code like

```
#lang racket

(display "Hello, World")
```

Then upon pressing ⌘+R will run that Racket code (this can surely be done with a simple script that runs `racket myfile.rkt` and gets the output) and print the output in the console on the bottom of Sublime Text 2. I'd also like to add a REPL in the console that evaluates Racket code otherwise. I really want to get working versions on both Windows and Mac.

Something like this:

[image: Something like this, without the error of course ...]

My problem is that I have no idea how to get started on this, could someone please point me in the right direction? This is something that I really want to get done :)

Thanks for any help, it's greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL). It likely is extensible in and of itself enough to support Racket, as there are already other Lisp-type languages in it like Clojure and Scheme. If you'd still like to build your own just for the fun of it, the source will certainly help give you some ideas.

---

***Update***

As of [version 2.0.0](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/blob/master/messages/2.0.0.txt), SublimeREPL now has a Racket REPL built in. Happy coding!